# Bash: How to list n random number of files (not head or tail)

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script

I have a large directory containing numerous files of similar kind. I have to send few random files for auditing. These files should not be from the top or bottom (eg. not in `head` or `tail`). This is sub process which I am struggling.

I want to get any number of files. It may be 10 or 2 or 3, but should not be in any order.

For example from this list of files:

```
10 1121231243 12 3124234ewdf 31243345 xaa 112 1121231243214 3 3124234ewdffd 3124334532 xab 1121 112123124321442334 3124 31243 3124334532324 xac 112123 1121ewszf 3124234 312433 file1
```

I would like to get a random subset like in this instance:

```
1121 112123124321442334 3124 1121ewszf
```

Comment: Why can't you use `head` or `tail`? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: I'm working in a company and I have encountered with a issue like this where It is a big directory, where some files in the middle, are to be sent for auditing. It's bigger issue and i got struck in  this sub-process.

Comment: It'd be better if you [described the real issue instead of your attempted solution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Not only is this a contrived question, but you'd also end up with possibly useless answers. Can you [edit] your question and tell us more about the situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use random `sort` (`-R` or `--random-sort`) and then `head` or `tail`:

`ls | sort -R | head -10`

Comment: Thanks. In my case I needed the same 10 items always, but in random order `ls | head -10 | sort -R`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort -R` to sort the list randomly, and then use the `$RANDOM` variable with `head` to get a random number of results:

```
ls | sort -R | head -n $(( $RANDOM % 10 + 1 ))
```

You will get 10 results or less (never zero)